# How to get name of website who using our script or web application

Tags: javascript, php, html, security

Hello friends i wanted to make a system to detect my web application i wanted to check how many domains using my web application and someone is using it illegally so i want to destory the this app remotely is it possible friends?
Any method via php or javascript to control my own web app remotely
I am using PHP to develope this admin panel

Comment: Server logs, see where the referrers are coming from.

Comment: How to ? Please explain more clearly

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. you have to use it. just check it's manual

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible using PHP or JavaScript.

First, referers can easily be faked, so you can not trust that.

Second, to delete files off of a remote computer using PHP (server only) or JavaScript (client based, but limited) is not possible.  PHP can't touch files on the client computer/phone, and JavaScript can't delete files as a security measure.

Comment: So how to track our web application on internet?